# Does the new pytz upgrade break Celery Beat's handling of Daylight Savings Time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, celery, pytz, celerybeat

I'm using the celery beat scheduler to run tasks on a daily basis.  For over a year, the following task was sent by Celery Beat without problems:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'daily-sync': {
        'task': 'my_app.workflow.daily_sync',
        'schedule': crontab(minute=0, hour=0, day_of_month='2-31'),
    },

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'US/Eastern'
```

Following daylight savings time, the task is no longer sent.  This is only happening for this one task, and this is the only task scheduled for midnight.  All other tasks are still being delivered.  I've checked the Celery beat logs, and the following entries stop appearing after November 7:

```
[2016-11-04 04:00:00,092: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task daily-sync (my_app.workflow.daily_sync)
```

As I said, this task has been executing for well over a year without problems.  During the last Daylight Savings Time, everything was still fine.  In investigating the problem further, I noticed that I recently upgrade pytz when installing a new python package.  From requirements.txt:

```
-pytz==2016.3
+pytz==2016.7
```

I've tried restarting Celery Beat and recreating the celerybeat-schedule files.  All without luck.  How can I get my task delivered again?  Do I have to migrate my `CELERY_TIMEZONE` to UTC to ensure this doesn't happen again?